# convert multiple arrays objects to single array, underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array which contain multiple objects, like

```
var val = [
    _id: ["5412fc1bd123cf7016674a92", "5412cf270e9ca9b517b43ca3"],
    _id: ["5412cf5a6cc4f4bc151fd220"]
];
```

I want to change to single array, like:

```
var val = [
    "5412fc1bd123cf7016674a92", 
    "5412cf270e9ca9b517b43ca3", 
    "5412cf5a6cc4f4bc151fd220"
];
```

I'm using  **_.pluck()** but its not giving me the output which I want. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure about your example code? Shouldn't it be an object containing multiple arrays instead?

Comment: yes i'm sure about my code.

Comment: Then it's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: I'm getting ids from arrays of objects and put all in single variable called 'val'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** This is 2019 and `Array.flat` is native.

```js
const val = {
  _id: ["5412fc1bd123cf7016674a92", "5412cf270e9ca9b517b43ca3"],
  _id2: ["5412cf5a6cc4f4bc151fd220"]
}

console.log(
  Object.values(val).flat()
)

// Without flat
console.log(
  Array.prototype.concat.apply(
    [],
    Object.values(val)
  )
)

// Without Object.values
console.log(
  Array.prototype.concat.apply(
    [],
    Object.keys(val).map(k => val[k])
  )
)
```

The following is all you need with lodash:

```
_.flatten(_.values(val))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input data is an object containing several arrays, like so:

```
var val = {
    _id: ["5412fc1bd123cf7016674a92", "5412cf270e9ca9b517b43ca3"],
    _id2: ["5412cf5a6cc4f4bc151fd220"]
};
```

You can get the desired array structure pretty easily using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
var flat = [];
for (var key in val) {
    flat = flat.concat(val[key]);
}
console.log(flat);
```

Output:

```
[ '5412fc1bd123cf7016674a92',
  '5412cf270e9ca9b517b43ca3',
  '5412cf5a6cc4f4bc151fd220' ]
```

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense, because keys must be unique. OP probably has a collection (array of objects)

Comment: Oops, copy-pasted the duplicate key.